# Inconsistent change in VmRSS or VmSize when looking at /proc/self/status

Tags: c++, bash, memory, redhat, virtual-memory

I have been investigating an issue with a customer on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6. I have seen similar behavior on Ubuntu as well. The customer is tracking the memory usage by outputting 
/proc/self/status

This happens in an ODBC application when using a specific ODBC driver but I suspect that is relevant to the problem.

The memory usage is being tracked (via calling /proc/self/status function pasted in then end) in various stages of the program, once before allocating some memory on the heap, once after freeing that memory and once after unloading the dynamic library.

When the amount of the allocated memory exceeds some value, the VmRSS does not go down immediately after freeing the memory, but does go down immediately after unloading the so file. When the amount of the allocated memory is small VmRSS goes down immediately after freeing the memory.

I have run valgrind on the application and I could not find any memory leak.
Any help, explanations, pointers to articles is very much appreciated.

```
void print_proc_status_vm()
{
  std::ifstream proc_status_fhandle;
  proc_status_fhandle.open("/proc/self/status");
  std::string s;
  int line=0;
  static std::map<std::string, int> memoryUsage;
  while(std::getline(proc_status_fhandle, s)){
    ++line;
    if( (line >=12) and (line <=17 ) and (line !=14) )
    {   
        char* str = new char[s.size()+1];
        strcpy(str, s.c_str());
        std::string key(strtok(str, "\t "));

        int value = atoi(strtok(NULL, "\t "));

        printf("%s   %d \n", key.c_str(), value - memoryUsage[key] );

       memoryUsage[key] = value;
       delete[] str;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This happens in a c++ application. Just pasted the code used inside the application for printing out the memory usage.

Comment: I used valgrind's massif profiler and it seems like the memory is being allocated/freed as expected regardless of the allocation size. So proc/self/status does not report the actual memory used by a process? Could someone comment on this?

Answer (score -1):

Once I encountered quite a similar problem with suricata - this program has a lot of small rules it loads into memory, and once developers added dynamic reload of rules, the program ended up constantly occupying twice as much of memory even though all the previous rules were freed after loading the new ones.

It was caused by a fact that there are a lot of rules, one malloc per rule, but each one takes not so much space => malloc internally used brk/sbrk (stack-like) instead of mmap => as original rules were below the new ones on a data segment, this segment hadn't been decreased even after gigabytes of original rules were freed.

The solution in this case is to allocate a big chunk of memory at once and then split it into smaller pieces manually.

As to a file, it is mmapped, so the memory could be immediately released after you unmap it.